# Unit Test case for Service Function which calls function from same service in for loop

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing Unit Test Cases for a service where one function1 calls another function2 in for loop. Function2 calls http.get('API'). Test case for function2 is working fine but Test case for Function1 gives error as : "Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match by function: ", found 2 requests."

My Code is Service is as follows:-

```js
getReport(Id: string) {
  const url = `${environment.PATH}/reports/${Id}`;
  const options: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  } = {
    responseType: 'blob'
  };
  return this.http.get(url, options)
    .map(
      (res) => {
        // return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
        return new Blob([res], {
          type: 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        });
      });
}

getReports(Ids: string[] = []) {
  const Links: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++) {
    this.getReport(Ids[i]).toPromise()
      .then(
        (res) => {
          const ext = Ids[i];
          saveAs(res, ext + '.xlsx');
        });
  }
}
```

Test Cases are as follows:

```js
it('getReport should return excel report', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController],
  (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    const reportService = getTestBed().get(Service);
    reportService.getReport('id').map(
        res => {
          expect(res).toBeTruthy();
          return Observable.of(res);
        }
      )
      .subscribe();
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(req => req.url.includes('url'));
    // Assert that the request is a GET.
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    // Respond with mock data, causing Observable to resolve.
    // Subscribe callback asserts that correct data was returned.
    req.flush(new Blob);
    // Finally, assert that there are no outstanding requests.
    httpMock.verify();
  }));

it('getReports should call getReport to each  ID', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController],
  (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    const reportService = getTestBed().get(Service);
    spyOn(reportService, 'getReport').and.callThrough();
    const sessList = ['id2'];
    reportService.getReports(sessList);
    for (let i = 0; i < sessList.length; i++) {
      reportService.getReport(sessList[i]).map(
          res => {
            expect(res).toBeTruthy();
            return Observable.of(res);
          }
        )
        .subscribe();
      const req = httpMock.expectOne(req => req.url.includes('url'));
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
      req.flush(new Blob);
    }
  }));
```